# Refresh Screen A when goBack with React Native using Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a simple doubt that I can hope somebody can help me with. I have a simple app that hava a main screen where loads all data that I get from a SQLite database, but, when I go to the 'Add To The Database Screen' and add some data and record in the database, I use a function to go back to the previous screen (`props.navigation.goBack()`).

Unfortunately, when I arrive at the screen A, my hook does not 'refresh' or update the data from the database. Is there a way to make it refresh the screen A to make a new call to the database and refresh data with the new data?

ps: to make the call to database, I use the today date to get data in a query, so my date does not update.

Here's my code:

ScreenA.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function ScreenA() {

   const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setData(getDataFromApi())
    }, []);

    return(
        <View>
            { apiResponse() }
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB') }}
                <Text>Add data</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

And here is the ScreenB.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function ScreenB() {

    function goBackToScreenA() {
        addDataToDatabase();
        props.navigation.goBack();
    }

    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { goBackToScreenA() }}>
                <Text>Go Back</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you show the code of `addDataToDatabase` method? are you doing any async task in that method that should be awaited ?

Comment: yes! it makes all async, the query will return a promise `export const addDataToDatabase = async (date) => {

    let db = new DB();

    let newData = await lista.getAllData(date);
    
    return newData;
}`

Comment: i meant the `addDataToDatabase` i think the method u put is `getDataFromApi`

Comment: you should consider marking the `addDataToDatabase` an async and when you call it prefix it with an await keyword `await addDataToDatabase()`

Comment: sorry, seventeen hours after coding makes me fell a little tired hahaha here's the code: `async function getDataFromApi(date) {

    let list = [];

    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(`select * from tasks where date_execution = ?`,[date], (_, { rows }) => {
            for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                list.push(rows.item(i));
            }

            resolve(list);
        })
    }));
}`

Comment: when you are calling it inside your `ScreenB`, try this `function goBackToScreenA() {
        await addDataToDatabase();
        props.navigation.goBack();
    }
`

Comment: I fixed this by killing the ScreenA to go to de the ScreenB and killing the ScreenB to go back to ScreenA using replace insted navigate, it works because the component will mount again like a first time and will make the call to database using the first effect to fetch the data, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've fixed this bug by killing the component to go to the ScreenB, I just use `props.navigation.replace('ScreenB')` insted use `navigate`. So, when I comeback to ScreenA, it just load the ScreenA again. Like the first time. And in the `goBack()` I make the same, change the go back with `replace('ScreenA')` after add the data to database.

Comment: This is not the way to solve issue. Like you're just killing the issue rather than solving it .

Answer (score 8):

If you are using reactnavigation then you can subscribe to the navigation lifecycle

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
  // Screen was focused
  // Do something
});

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function ScreenA() {
    useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
            setData(getDataFromApi());
        }, [])
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this passing props to next screen. when get back from that screen need to call that props.

eg.

Screen A

```
onBackEvent=(event)=>{console.log(event)}

onPress=()=>{
this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenB",{onBackEvent:this.onBackEvent.bind(this)})
}
```

Screen B
When you are going back just add this line before back

```
this.props.route.params.onBackEvent({update:true})
```